# Настройка виртуального хоста на сервере

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

Доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь настроить виртуальный хост на Apache таким образом (10.0.0.8 адрес сервера в локальной сети):

```
NameVirtualHost 10.0.0.8:8080  
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.8:8080> 
    DocumentRoot "c:\vhost\www.site.ru\web" 
    ServerName www.site.ru   
</VirtualHost>
```

В файле host прописываю строку

> 10.0.0.8  www.site.ru

На сервере по имени  *www.site.ru* я могу зайти на этот сайт, но на клиенте мне  выводится сообщение о том, что браузер не может найти сервер *www.site.ru*. В файле host на клиенте прописана точно такая же запись, как и на сервере. Пинг на адрес 10.0.0.8 от клиента приходит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина такого поведения? Что нужно настроить, чтобы клиент смог увидеть этот сайт?

Comment: Проблема явно не в апаче, а в ваших файлах host. Вы пинг не на ip пробуйте, а на имя. И если пинг так же не находит имени, то значит вы в какой то не тот файл написали что такое 10.0.0.8

Comment: Вы правы, ping на www.site.ru не проходит

Comment: На клиенте стоит windows 7 x64, а host нашла по адресу c:/windows/system32/drivers/et, собственно, там все и прописывала

Comment: Хм.. нашла еще один hosts по адресу C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-w..nfrastructure... может данные берутся оттуда?

Comment: первый путь правильный который system32/drivers/etc только файл не host, а hosts

Comment: согласна))) но все равно не работает...

Comment: Вот это очень странно. не сталкивался. всегда на скору руку что бы имя добавить туда пишу и всегда и везде работает. Единственное что приходит на ум, может какой нибудь особо злобный антивирус решает что не надо hosts работать (вирусы часто сайты через него подменяют). Или еще что то в стеке tcp/ip засело, что по своему решает ...

Comment: Насчет антивируса выглядит очень даже многообещающе. На машине стоит Касперский и он очень там злой) хотя на сервере он тоже стоит и там  hosts читается....

Comment: а что такого может быть в стеке tcp/ip? это можно как-нибудь увидеть?

Comment: Нет, с этим проблемы. попробуйте для начала приостановить работу касперского

Comment: Отключила антивирус, но www.site.ru так и  остался недоступным...

Comment: может эта ошибка быть связана как-то с тем, что клиент-виртуальная машина?

Comment: Вы ping проверяли, он точно так же как браузер не может по имени определить ? Виртуалка по идее ни чем от обычных не отличается. Для очищения совести можно конечно прописать еще в hosts на основной ОС в которой виртуалка запущена.

Comment: да я пробовала и по ping и через браузер, все равно не находит.. Попробую прописать на основной, может и вправду что-нибудь получиться)

Comment: P.S. настройки сервера все-таки верны, так как на обычном компьютере в локальной сети, все заработало)

Comment: Большое Вам СПАСИБО))))) сработало)